# Excel vba to filter data and set value in filtered list to variable

Tags: vba, excel

Im having a bit of trouble with my code. Im trying to filter the values in column M and then set one of the values in M to the variable deptName. This works for every iteration except for one and instead of setting deptName to the value in M it sets it equal to the value in A1. It only does this for one of the iterations and I'm not sure why.

```
  For criteria = 1 To UBound(degreeArray)
    degreeWS.range(fields).AutoFilter Field:=degreeColumn, Criteria1:=degreeArray(criteria)
    degreeWS.range("A2:A" & lrd).EntireRow.Copy

    Dim deptName As Variant
     range("M2", Cells(Rows.count, "M").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 1).Select
     deptName = Selection
```

Here is an example of the data

```
 A        B      C        D     E       F      G    H     I           J       K   L        M
ID     FName   LName          Degree  Major   Col  Dept1 Dept1Name   Major2  Col  Dept2  Dept2Name
100    Jack    Smith           MBA    MAJOR1   UK  BIO   BIOLOGY     MAJOR2   UK  CHEM   CHEMISTRY
101    Sally   Johnson         BS     MAJOR1   UK  EDU   EDUCATION   MAJOR2   UK  BIO    BIOLOGY
102    Bryan   Carter          BSB    MAJOR1   UK  CHEM  CHEMISTRY   MAJOR2   UK  EDU    EDUCATION
104    Mason   Harper          BS     MAJOR1   UK  BIO   BIOLOGY     MAJOR2   UK  EDU    EDUCATION
104    Harry   Potter          MBA    MAJOR1   UK  CHEM  CHEMISTRY   MAJOR2   UK  BIO    BIOLOGY
```

Comment: Avoid using select at all costs....

Comment: what could I use instead of select @Lowpar

Comment: @Cocoberry2526 use something like: `deptname = range("M2", Cells(Rows.count, "M").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 1).value`

Comment: @Cocoberry2526 it must be something to do with the offset? try debugging with F8 and see exactly why it is happening, seems strange, we would need to see the data.

Comment: I can't show you the data because it is confidential,  but I went through with F8 and that is how I figured out is was going to cell A1 instead of the next visible cell in column M. For all of the other iterations it goes directly to the first visible cell in column M

Comment: @Lowpar I tried doing what you suggested earlier and it still used the value for cell A1

Comment: The end(xlup) must be causing the cell to return to "A1", do you have an example of the data?

Comment: @Lowpar I've added an example of the data in the question box

Comment: how is the degreearray populated? static list? see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43276259/excel-vba-auto-filter-and-advanced-filter-usage-error/43276651?noredirect=1#comment73626798_43276651

Comment: @Lowpar I have added in an answer the full code so maybe that'll help us figure out the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140192/discussion-between-lowpar-and-cocoberry2526).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem was with deptName range. I added `End(xlDown)` to the end of it before the .value and now the code works perfect.

```
Dim deptName As Variant
       deptName = range("M1:M" & Cells(Rows.count, "M").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).End(xlDown).Value
```